# Acquiring data of Billboards on USA

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, united-states, data-collection, data-mining

I have this task on ArcGis consisting on retrieving landownership data of every billboards' in USA, etc... from where should I start ?

Comment: Have you tried [opendata.se]?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good question should include your own research and attempt.  What have you tried, where have you looked?  Same goes for your private land ownership question in your comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, the datasources or data sets is extremely sparse and concentrate to particular geographies, not entirely the US. However, these two websites I came across can assist you in finding out more about your data:

[A Look at the Kentucky Transportation Cabinet's (KYTC) Billboard Application](https://www.gis.fhwa.dot.gov/documents/Newsletter_Spring2011.asp)
[USC student uses crowdsourcing to map billboard locations](https://giszone.blogs.bucknell.edu/2011/02/09/usc-student-uses-crowdsourcing-to-map-billboard-locations/)

Comment: I couldn't find any data on these ws. I guess this type of data isn't available yet.
What about private land ownership?? where can I retrieve this kind of data for free??

Comment: http://billboardmap.usc.edu/Services/Billboards/Default.aspx has some sparse data, your options are limited unless you do field work (time consuming) to get the data raw.